# How to get json data coming from ajax and show it prefilled in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Following is the code that Ii have used to get the response in `json`.
but when I add alert `alert(response.Subject);` it returns "undefined"

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="subject" value='Subject'>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ebays/prefilledcontentajax",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: {
        Type: $("#Type").val(),
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response); // it show the json that response returns. I want to show in the input box prefilled with the data that response return 
    }
});
```

please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `val` to set value in the textbox

```
$('#subject').val(response[0].Subject);
```

Also, you might want to change the `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ebays/prefilledcontentajax",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: {
        Type: $("#Type").val(),
    },
    dataType: "json",
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    success: function (response) {
        // response is JSON
        $('#subject').val(response[0].Subject);
    }
});
```

`val`

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

`ajax`

> Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: the response i am getting is :- [{"Subject":"What can we do to make your experience with us better?","PlainTextBody":"testtts"}]
hw to get the subject from the json

Comment: @user123456 Check updated answer, Notice: 1. `dataType` 2. `success` body

Comment: when i add alert  alert(response.Subject); it says undefined

Comment: @user123456 check udpated answer! `alert(response[0].Subject`, use ajax as in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

It really depends the construction of your JSON object, but standart is responseText that you parse with JS

maybe you try to get the response text or response JSON

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ebays/prefilledcontentajax",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: {
        Type: $("#Type").val(),
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response.responseText));
        //or 
        console.log(JSON.parse(response.responseJSON));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this:

```
$('#subject').val(response.Subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's really easy. Just add:

```
$('#subject').val(response.Subject);
```

in your success handler.